# where git clone stored files

Tags: git, clone

Hi I cloned https://github.com/hackerpain/domaining and can't find it in my Windows, the reason I want to find it is that it has a .txt file and I want to modify it.

I use Ubuntu, and I have a question if I run:

```
git clone https://github.com/savebreach/domaining.git
```

is that mean the file is downloaded to my computer like download zip?

Comment: Are you using WSL?

Comment: Git clone will create a folder in your Ubuntu `/home/$USER`.

Answer (score 0):

`git clone https://github.com/savebreach/domaining.git` downloads the domaining project and creates a folder named domaining for it in your current working directory which is your home folder by default.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/savebreach/domaining.git
Cloning into 'domaining'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 147, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (147/147), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (146/146), done.
remote: Total 147 (delta 68), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (147/147), 36.96 KiB | 591.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (68/68), done.
```

The instructions for installing Domaining Automation are found in README.md.